# Use data saved with `*inchstr()` to restore screen contents

Tags: c, ncurses, curses

I needed a way to save screen content to a buffer (as opposed to a `FILE` as `putwin()` does) for a quick in-memory save-and-restore, so I looked in [Ncurses documentation](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html) and found the [`*inchstr()`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inchstr.3x.html) family of functions, which looks just what I needed.

So I saved data in a function that can be simplified as:

```
chtype buffer[LINES][COLS+1];
for (int line = 0; line < LINES; line++)
    mvinchnstr(line, 0, buffer[line], COLS);
```

Question is: how to *restore* this saved data to screen in an efficient manner?

I know I can use 2 nested loops with `addch()`, but wouldn't restoring character-per-character defeat the whole purpose of using `inchnstr()` in the first place? Is there an `add*()` counterpart of `inchnstr()` that takes a null-terminated array of `chtype` chars and print that?

If there isn't, what is the purpose of the `*inchnstr()` family? Is there a better approach for saving and restoring screen contents to and from memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`addchstr` and friends](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addchstr.3x.html).